# android 10 camera image issue

Tags: android, android-camera

i am getting trying to get image from camera in android 10 but it is not working properly.i have used this code for getting image from camera

this is my intent

```
val takePhotoIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, createImageFile())
startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, 3)
```

her it is my file provider

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths>
      <files-path
        name="images"
        path="." />
    </paths>
```

here it is my function to create file path

```
public static File createImageFile(
    Context context,
    String dirName,
    String fileName,
    String fileType) {
try {
    File file = createDir(context, dirName);
    File image = new File(file.getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + fileName + fileType);
    if (!image.getParentFile().exists()) {
        image.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
    image.createNewFile();
    return image;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
}
```

here it is file provider define in manifest file

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.android.restuarantuser.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

Comment: What issue you are facing @Sagar

Comment: camera open in android 10 and image is alos capture but when i try to get on onActivityresult app crash @sumitsingh

Comment: add the crash log in ques

Comment: Facing same issue. Any solution?